# Random Forest: how to output important variables for a given point

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

My Random Forest classification model contains 500 decision trees, and trained on 200 variables and 10,000 data points. Each decision tree is responsible for a particular sub-region in 200-dimensional parameter space, and is represented by several input variables.

I want to implement two things:

- recognize which of 500 decision trees is related to a given point X
- output list of variables included in the decision tree.
  Ideally, it should be a single function call:

```
list_of_variables <- getSignificantVariables(RF, X)
```

where RF is a random forest model, and X is a row in the training (or testing) data set.

I tried to use existent API in the `RandomForest` package. The function `GetTree(n)` outputs a table with information related to the tree number n. It is possible to associate variable names with variable numbers taken from the table. But how can we recognize which of 500 decision trees is related to the given point X?

Comment: I think VarImp() does that, read the RF vignette and you will know which function it is! Best of luck!

Comment: Gaurav, thank you for your answer. But VarImp() does not work for me. It returns a list of important variables in general, for the entire data set, while I need such a list for each row X in the data set:                            list_of_variables <- getSignificantVariables(RF, X). In other words, I need to loop through N rows in the dataset, and generate N lists of important variables. I expect some rows to have identical lists, but the lists of important variables can be completely different for different rows.

Comment: @Vladmir , I am not sure how can one get variable importance for each _row_ in X ( X being the dataset) as there is only a single observation for each variable in that one row. Variable Impartnace as a concept( to my understanding) is based on how much error each variable reduces as compared to a mean or a nested model. So i can understand if one wants Variable Importance by each tree in RF but each row is something I am unaware of. Would like to know how you get it done!

Comment: Gaurav, I understand your point, you're right. But this is a requirement. My first idea was to use variables included in each individual tree in the random forest. But then I realized that each tree is based on 60% of the entire dataset, and the trees are voting. Overlapping of the trees over the dataset does not allow to extract variables related to a small data subset. So, I decided to use combination of cluster analysis and correlation analysis. I expect each cluster to have a specific set of correlated variables.